# Generalized linear mixed model: what is base dependent variable?

Tags: r, glmm

I have run Generalized linear mixed model with glmer in lme4. I use R version 3.0.1. My dependent variable is binary (correct or wrong). And this is my results:

```
> glmer16 <- glmer(result ~ (1|item) + (1|speaker) + vowel + sex + cat + dog + exposure + frequency + v00004 + v00024 + v00034 + v00044, data=data1.frame, family=binomial)
> summary(glmer16)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: realisation ~ (1 | item) + (1 | speaker) + vowel + sex + cat +      dog + exposure + frequency + v00004 + v00024 + v00034 +      v00044 
   Data: data1.frame 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
 881.7026  958.6402 -426.8513  853.7026 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 speaker (Intercept) 7.0291   2.651   
 item    (Intercept) 0.5084   0.713   
Number of obs: 1800, groups: speaker, 50; item, 12

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 15.52018    5.33634   2.908  0.00363 ** 
vowelhigh    0.16750    0.55907   0.300  0.76449    
vowellow     0.70981    0.63194   1.123  0.26134    
sexmale      1.37080    1.03228   1.328  0.18420    
cat         -0.11460    0.09537  -1.202  0.22953    
dog         -0.05460    0.03633  -1.503  0.13286    
exposure    -0.00404    0.01564  -0.258  0.79613    
frequency   -0.01709    0.15594  -0.110  0.91272    
v00004      -2.83445    0.66039  -4.292 1.77e-05 ***
v00024       0.29687    0.55868   0.531  0.59515    
v00034       0.43899    0.58656   0.748  0.45421    
v00044       0.36663    0.65130   0.563  0.57349    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My questions are: 1) Does v00004 decrease the result of 'wrong' or 'correct'? and 2) what does it mean by significant at the intercept?

Comment: How is `result` coded? Also, in your code, the dependent variable is `result` but in the **R** output, the dependent variable is called `realisation`.

Comment: My result is coded as either 'wrong' or 'correct'. Oh yeah sorry. I have changed it a bit when posted on this website. Anyway, when I plot a boxplot, it turns out that v00004 of 'correct' is higher than 'wrong'. Can I say that v00004 decreases the 'wrong' results for -2.83445?

Comment: As Nick Stauner alluded to in his answer, it would be easier if you told us exactly how `result` is coded. For example, does wrong=0 and correct=1?

Comment: Smilig, no I didn't code it in number. I coded it in either 'wrong' or 'correct' as I thought that R can deal with text. Do I need to change DV into number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significant negative coefficient for `v00004` indicates that this variable relates to a lower probability of `result` being the higher value of the two it can take. If you've coded it so $\text{correct > wrong}$, this would mean that as `v00004` increases, wrong results are more likely. Otherwise, it means the opposite. Whether you can say this is a causal relationship depends on your research design: you would probably need to have conducted a true experiment to establish causality.

These $z$-tests are all of whether the model coefficients differ significantly from zero. The significance of the intercept represents the probability that its coefficient – 15.52 in this case – would be at least as far from zero if you sampled randomly again from the same population, assuming that the true value of the model intercept in the population is zero. This is probably not a very useful statistic if you don't have special interest in your model's intercept.

Comment: Nick, could I ask you to make sure again that I understand your reply? When I plot a boxplot, it turns out that v00004 of 'correct' is higher than 'wrong'. Can I say that when v00004 decreases, the 'wrong' results increase for -2.83445? / For intercept, no actually I don't have any special interest in intercept, and might not report it in my results.

Comment: Sounds like you probably coded `result` so $\text{correct > wrong}$, but you've got much better info than I do, since you've controlled so many other variables in your model. It seems you need to figure out how R has coded `result`.

Comment: Okay I will study now R code results. Thanks very much Nick Stauner.

Comment: Glad I've been helpful. Try `as.numeric(factor(result))` and see if that helps you figure out which is being coded as the higher-level value...There might be more appropriate ways of doing that, but this way ought to work in its own clumsy fashion.

Comment: To Nick Stauner, after I put this '> as.numeric(factor(data1.frame$realisation))', I get this:  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2.... (and many other rows). And in my data 2 = wrong, and 1 = correct. So that means that 2 > 1, right? And R will pick 2 as my DV?

Comment: You have told R to treat `result` as your dependent variable. If `2 = 'wrong'`, then as `v00004` increases, so does the probability of a wrong `result`.

Comment: Yeah!! I got your point now. Thanks very much for your replies and your time.